# Downscaling resolution to fit screen 

Tags: laptop, display, resolution

I have an Asus laptop with a 1366x768 screen. I'm finding I would like to have everything smaller so I would have more room to work. Is there a way to get the graphics card to display 1080p and then downscale it to fit the screen, thus making everything smaller?

I'm running Windows 7 Professional and my graphics card can handle up to 2560x1600.

Comment: Yes, and if you actually do that, everything will look like crap. I suggest you try adjusting font sizes. Ctrl+(plus/minus) is an often used keyboard shortcut within various applications for adjusting font sizes. You may also want to adjust these sizes on a system-wide level. What OS are you using?

Comment: The card will not display the 2560X1600 on the built in display.  That is likley max on external monitor. @Doc has a good suggestion

Comment: @JamesTSnell Please, how?

Comment: @Qwerty: How what? To change system font scale for Windows 10? It's in the Ease of Use settings, under Display. Here's a doc on it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028566/windows-10-change-the-size-of-text

Comment: @JamesTSnell To use larger than hw supported desktop resolution with downscaling to the supported one, so that everything is smaller, not only just text.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-your-screen-resolution) guide from Microsoft.

When you find the resolution that you like, press **apply**.

Comment: Achemmm... why a down vote?

Comment: I believe it is not possible to set higher than maximum supported resolution.