# How to display higher than native desktop resolution?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

Windows certainly ***can*** display higher than native resolution on an LCD screen as proven via this random experiment where I have two displays with different resolutions while in **Duplicate Desktop** mode, where the smaller screen displays a desktop originating from the larger screen.

So,

> ### How to achieve this *Duplication* downscaling trick on *two separate desktops* *(Extended mode)*?

Notice the screenshot of Display 1 below, where it says

> **Desktop resolution**         3840 x 2160
>   **Active signal resolution** 1920 x 1080

**Setup:**

> HP ProBook 650 G2
>   Intel HD Graphics 530
>   Display 1: BuiltIn 14" display @ 1920x1080
>   Display 2: External 24" DELL P2415Q @ 3840x2160

Attempt at making a screenshot via <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> of whole screen, or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> or via "screen snipping" results in this weird downscaled FHD desktop, while the image resolution remains UHD.

**Screenshot:**
[image: desktop screenshot virtual]

**Perceived:** *every time I attempted to make a screenshot, the screen would flash similarly to this*
[image: desktop screenshot perceived]

**Settings:**
[image: display1][image: display2][image: display modes]]

note:
I had to take photographs instead of screenshots, because of the weird desktop downscaling as shown in Screenshot/Perceived comparison.

PS:
I appreciate your concerns that the result would look shite, *(in fact it is possible to read from it without difficulties,)* but this is exactly what I am trying to achieve for years and I am desperate already. I will be using the 4K screen for main activities and the UHD-downscaled-to-FHD screen for browser feedback while developing.

related:
[Change screen resolution to exceed the maximum on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/50501/change-screen-resolution-to-exceed-the-maximum-on-windows-7)
[Downscaling resolution to fit screen](https://superuser.com/questions/338423/downscaling-resolution-to-fit-screen) 
[Can i trick windows into displaying a larger resolution?](https://superuser.com/questions/110161/can-i-trick-windows-into-displaying-a-larger-resolution)